# Can't get VideoCapture property as the property identifier are not defined

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to process frames in a video file, and to know what is the current frame position in the video.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Videos/IMG_2483.MOV')
print("Position : %d" % cap.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
```

I keep getting this error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC'
```

I guess I am wrongly calling the attribute "CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC". I've been looking everywhere but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` is deprecated in your installed version of Opencv, Change it to `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC`. Works good for me on Opencv 3.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I have to change my version of OpenCV ? I have already tried to call cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC

Comment: @lilian No simply replace `print("Position : %d" % cap.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))` to `print("Position : %d" % cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I've been misreading your answer. 
If I download the latest version of OpenCV, would i have to use cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC ?

Comment: No maybe the tutorials you read were using an very older version of OpenCV, `cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` is deprecated, You can use `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` even after updating.