# Detect timestamp of position of object detected from an mp4 video using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect objects from an mp4 video file using OpenCV in Python. I am able to detect the objects in the video.

I would like to get the timestamp of the position at which the object was detected in the video file and write it to a text file.

Here is my code so far:

```
import cv2

my_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('toy.xml')

def detect(gray, frame):
    toys= my_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in toys:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        #Logic to write time stamp to file goes here
    return frame 

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('home.mp4')
cv2.startWindowThread()
while True: 
    _, frame = video_capture.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    canvas = detect(gray, frame) 
    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to use VideoCapture's method get() using property identifier like this:

```
 video_capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
```

but get an error ***name 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC' is not defined***

Seems like cv2 does not have this method or property identifier implemented.

Is there any other way in cv2 to implement what I want?

Please help.

---

**SOLVED**

This will print timestamp of the position of object everytime it is detected in the video.
Here is the working code:

```
import cv2

my_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('toy.xml')

def detect(gray, frame):
    toys= my_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in toys:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        print("Toy Detected at: "+str(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)))
    return frame 

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('home.mp4')
cv2.startWindowThread()
while True: 
    _, frame = video_capture.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    canvas = detect(gray, frame) 
    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cv2 does have the property implemented, but the full name needs to be used.

This should work

```
import cv2

my_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('toy.xml')

def detect(gray, frame):
    toys= my_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in toys:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        #Logic to write time stamp to file goes here
    return frame 

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('home.mp4')
cv2.startWindowThread()
while True: 
    _, frame = video_capture.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    canvas = detect(gray, frame) 
    print (video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))
    cv2.imshow('Video', canvas) 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i.e. you want the property of the instance `video_capture` not the generic class `VideoCapture` and the property name is prefixed by the class `cv2.`. The property name is either `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC`or `CV_CAP_PROP_MSEC` - depending on the OpenCV version (see [Can't get VideoCapture property as the property identifier are not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346018/cant-get-videocapture-property-as-the-property-identifier-are-not-defined) ).

Comment: Yes you are right, I changed it but still get an error. Updated question.

Comment: Thank you @Chris Hill. The print needed to have braces around print(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)). This works!